# Codename One - BrowserComponent: allow browsing only on two domains

Tags: codenameone

How can I force the BrowserComponent to do browsing only on two domains?

Use case: the BrowserComponent has to change page because any legal reason, for example the user clicks a link or the page does a redirect (by javascript, metatag, http header redirect, etc.). If the new page is on domain1 or domain2, it's ok and BrowserComponent can load it; if it's on any other domain, the BrowserComponent should call the O.S. native browsing tool (for example, Android can show a browser picker).

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what `BrowserNavigationCallback` exists for. It's a powerful tool that allows you to communicate on the native browser thread and can block any navigation that isn't there. FYI Since this is the native browser thread it's crucial that you don't block it and don't access the EDT from it.

The underlying JavaScript bridge is also implemented on top of this where the JS code sends a navigation request to the Java code.

Comment: Ok, I found some documentation: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html#_navigationcallback Is the following code correct for the EDT? [https://gist.github.com/jsfan3/a7627e9e377a740dbc4a2838853bf201](https://gist.github.com/jsfan3/a7627e9e377a740dbc4a2838853bf201) (I didn't find a way to put formatted code in a comment, that's why I used an external link, I'm sorry)

Comment: Yes. You used `callSerially` which is the exact right way to do this!